# Getting AD name of user in Jquery/Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to capture the persons AD name as it will do a look up when posting.

In my razor view I use @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name and it displays correctly such as DOMAIN\rlake.

So in my jquery script i have

```
<script>
var usrName = "@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name";       
        console.log(usrName);
</script>
```

however the console is showing it as DOMAINlake.  The \r is missing.  Tried to specifically store \r and write that to the console but returns nothing so I'm assuming this may have something to do with it being interpreted as the end of a row or carriage return.  Is this the case, is there a way around this?

I have a work around by

```
<div>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name, new { id = "ModelName", Value = @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name } )</div>
```

and passing that back to the controller in Ajas works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode the value:

```
var usrName = "@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)";
```

In that case it will be rendered as escaped Javascript and it will be safe to use in your code.